# SAlesforce Mobile App

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, salesforce-mobile-app

Salesforce Mobile App: LWC Navigation to Standard New Record Page Errors when State Includes defaultFieldValues. What's the workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm&release=224&type=5), Custom buttons and links that pass default field values to a new record aren't supported to Lightning Out, Lightning communities, or the Salesforce mobile app. and currently there is no workaround.

Currently, there is no workaround and you might want to review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdksyUAB/navigate-to-a-records-create-page-with-default-field-values-for-mobile) and upvote.

Comment: Does that mean, can I say that we will have to build the form from scratch, including Save functionality?